# NAT правило откидывает некоторые ип

Tags: сеть, debian, маршрутизация, iptables

Нужно сделать GRE без потери ИП клиентов

[Инструкция по которой делал всё](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/84067/)

Команды на хосте A:

```
auto tun0
iface tun0 inet static
  address 192.168.10.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  pointopoint 192.168.10.1
  pre-up modprobe ip_gre
  pre-up iptunnel add tun0 mode gre local XXX.251.152.XXX remote XX.89.21.XX ttl 255 dev eno1
  up ifconfig tun0 multicast
  post-up ip ru add from 192.168.10.2 lookup tun0 priority 32765
  post-up ip ro add default via 192.168.10.1 dev tun0 src 192.168.10.2 table tun0
  pre-down ip ro del default via 192.168.10.1 dev tun0 src 192.168.10.2 table tun0
  pre-down ip ru del from 192.168.10.2 lookup tun0 priority 32765
  post-down iptunnel del tun0
```

Хост B(Сам роутер):

```
auto tun0
iface tun0 inet static
  address 192.168.10.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  pointopoint 192.168.10.2
  pre-up modprobe ip_gre
  pre-up ip tunnel add tun0 mode gre local XX.89.21.XX remote XX.251.152.XX ttl 255 dev eth0
  up ifconfig tun0 multicast
  up arp -sD 192.168.10.2 eth0 pub
  post-down ip tunnel del tun0
```

И команды найстройки на хосте B:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 901 -j DNAT --to 192.168.10.2:901
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

В итоге какие-то адреса могут коннект, а другие нет

> [image: kek]

Как такое получилось и как исправить?

Comment: маска при pointopoint желательна /32 и скорее всего проблемы с проверялкой

Comment: @eri, у меня самого наблюдалась такая ситуация. Как только менялся ип - порт переставал работать

Comment: Зачем он менялся?

Comment: @eri, у меня на компьютере динамический ип. И странное поведение у этого GRE т.е иногда пакет может проходить, а на следующий день на этом же провайдере он уже не работает. Но уже работает, к примеру, у моих соседей